# How to handle a download alert in Firefox when clicking on a link using watir?

Tags: firefox, watir, watir-webdriver

When I click on a link of a web page in firefox browser with ruby watir:

```
ie.input(:id, "c_ImageButton_Text").click
```

The `.text` file starts downloading, then an alert exists with this: "What should Firefox do with this file". I want to disable this alert.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the profile to always download the specific file type. This is done by setting the `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk` property.

For example, to always download the pdf:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf"

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```

The property is comma separated list of MIME types. See Scott Alister's post on "[Determining file MIME types to autosave using Firefox & Watir-WebDriver](http://watirmelon.com/2011/09/07/determining-file-mime-types-to-autosave-using-firefox-watir-webdriver/)" for details on how to determine the applicable MIME type.

Note that configuring this setting is the same as a user going to Firefox's Options > Applications tab, which allows specifying actions on a per file type.

Answer (score 1):

I tried succesfully Justin Ko's solution and thats work fine for me..I suppose for your case, you were trying for .txt extension ..for that case..solution will be this:

to always download the txt:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "text/csv"

b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
```